# MVC setting up model id value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to MVC so please bear with me.

As a learning project I've decided to make a Fantasy Football website.  The NFL has a really cool api that lets you download TONS of stats and other info.  As part of the data stream, each player has an id number (actually they have like 3 ids but I'll just use the main one).

Here is the problem:  I want to set up my models to use the playerId value (passed in from an AJAX call on the NFL api) as a PK on my Player class and FK on several other classes/tables.  However, you normally can't assign the PK Identity value on a db.  I did a lot of searching for a workaround and tried several tricks but none worked.  I tried playing with the db manually and ended up ruining the project and having to start over.  I've thought of making the playerId a surrogate key but that seems needlessly complicated.  Theoretically I would periodically call the api for updates and those are all tied to that playerId value so making that playerId the PK is what makes the most sense.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Your PK and the NFL PK do not need to match, and they should not since they are not the same source of data. If you were Restore there database it would make sense to have that as a PK. You can Save that NFL PK as an Int and Indexed,it will be Unique, Just not the PK.

Comment: Sounds like you don't want the PK to be an `Identity` column, right?  Why is it?

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework for this?

Comment: @juanvan  If the nfl id is not the PK then on the Stats table the FK pointing to the Players table will not associate (directly) with the nfl id.  However,  when doing updates (fetching data from the api) the data stream will only have the nfl's id and not my pk id value.  Thus in order to update the Stats table (and any other tables involved) I'd first have to  associate the nfl's id to my pk and then update the Stats table from there.  This seems very inefficient.

Comment: @DWright Yes, I'm using EF Model First.  My background is more of a db first approach and I'm used to being able to query as needed for any data.  I'm not used to this *magic* behind the scenes stuff.

Comment: The problem is merely in your approach. If your only goal is persist the data from the NFL API, then perhaps SQL is not your best option. A NoSQL store like Redis would be much more flexible. Or, if you're going to be doing searching and analysis on this data, anyways, consider importing it directly into something like Elasticsearch. They even have "rivers" that allow you set up a automatic refreshing from an external datasource like an API so you can pretty much just set it and forget it. - Edit: rivers are deprecated, but you could still use a console app or something.

Comment: Have you tried setting the playerid column as your pk, but turning off Identity on the column?  Then on the EF side, you can mark this as not generated in the database, perhaps using `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` annotation.

Comment: @DWright  Yes, I tried that.  That allowed me to pass in the value but when the db actually tried to do the insert it would throw an exception.  I found another thread which said you have to turn it on of the db side and had a small script for that (I can't find it at the moment) but it still threw an exception every time.

Comment: What exception did it throw?

Comment: Also have you tried the apporach where you have your own id, but you use player_id as an additional unique id, as suggested by others above?

Comment: @DWright  I forget exactly what the exception was but something along the lines of "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Player' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."  I found a script which was supposed to set IDENTITY_INSERT to "ON" but the error persisted.

Comment: @DWright I've tried using id as the primary key and then loading the value from the nfl api into playerId but that generates an error saying you can only have 1 identity on a table.  I tried several different spellings (e.g. nflPid) but always got the same error.  Basically, if I have to properties like '%id%' then it gives the error.

Comment: Can you go to the column in SQL Server and make it not be an Identity column.  That's why it is doing this.

Comment: @DWright  Last night, while working on this, I tried messing with the sql directly.  All I ended up doing was breaking the migration and, in the end, I had to completely start the project over from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this to work.

First, add the annotation to the PK (playerId in my case.

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
```

Second, when you do a migration you have to proof read it.  I ran into quite a few errors because the migration code was just plain wrong.  In one case I changed the name of a PK column and the code tried to add the new PK column before dropping the old one.  All I had to do to correct this was to rearrange the steps.  Make sure to strip off the "identity: true" from the column which is to be the PK.

*Note:  My issues with the migration tool may be in part due to my using a version of VS2012 which I haven't updated in a while.  Some of the kinks may have been worked out since then.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off autoincrementing on your primary key column in your database. If your using SQL Server then don't set identity column. Set up your model like so:

```
public class Table_1
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
  public int playerId {get; set;}
  public string player_name { get; set; }
}
```

Then set playerId when you create the record.

Comment: Well, you are half right, but there is more I have to do than just this (though that is part of the solution).  Basically, the migration generated code is terrible.  But, if you rearrange the lines in the migration code and remove the "identity: true" where you don't want it, then you can get it to work.

Comment: @nurdyguy You did not state a clear question in your post. Thus I provided a solution to what I thought might help.

Comment: Your solution does help and I would have given you +1 if I could (my rank it too low).  I found the full solution a little before you posted but haven't had a chance to sit down and explain it fully.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to turn off the Identity specification on the SQL Server side: [image]